# Jquery function not working on re-clicking on the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a simple Future Value calculator.

On the first click of the submit button everything works perfectly,  but if i have to change one of the values and recalculate it, fv function does not work. Therefore if i have to recalculate the value i have to refresh the page again and again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var rate = $('#rate').val();
        var nper = $('#nper').val();
        var pmt = $('#pmt').val();
        var pv = $('#pv').val();
        fv(rate, nper, pmt, pv);
        fv = fv.toFixed(0);
        $('#fv').attr('value', fv);
    });
});

function fv(rate, nper, pmt, pv) {
    fv_pv = pv * (Math.pow((1 + (rate / 100)), nper));
    fv_annuity = pmt * (((Math.pow((1 + (rate / 100)), nper)) - 1) / (rate / 100));
    fv = fv_pv + fv_annuity;
    return fv;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

.attr(...) is only getting the objects value at the start (when the html is created). val() is getting the object's property value which can change many times.

```
var result = null;
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var rate = $('#rate').val();
    var nper = $('#nper').val();
    var pmt = $('#pmt').val();
    var pv = $('#pv').val();
    fv(rate, nper, pmt, pv);
    result =  parseFloat(result).toFixed(0);
    $('#fv').val(result);
});
   
function fv(rate, nper, pmt, pv) {
    var fv_pv = pv * (Math.pow((1 + (rate / 100)), nper));
    var fv_annuity = pmt * (((Math.pow((1 + (rate / 100)), nper)) - 1) / (rate / 100));
    result = fv_pv + fv_annuity;
};
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/28shomud/1/

Comment: Made changes as suggested by you but still the same issue... no progress

Comment: @aggarwal, I have updated my answer and also demo added.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the function fv declaration with `fv = fv.toFixed(0);` So 'fv' is no longer a function after the first submit.

Change

`fv = fv.toFixed(0);`

to

`var fvalue = fv.toFixed(0);`

Perhaps the same is happening in the fv function. Make sure to always use 'var' for local variables.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var rate = $('#rate').val();
        var nper = $('#nper').val();
        var pmt = $('#pmt').val();
        var pv = $('#pv').val();
        fv(rate, nper, pmt, pv);
        var fval = fv.toFixed(0);
        $('#fv').val(fval);
    });
});

function fv(rate, nper, pmt, pv) {
    var fv_pv = pv * (Math.pow((1 + (rate / 100)), nper));
    var fv_annuity = pmt * (((Math.pow((1 + (rate / 100)), nper)) - 1) / (rate / 100));
    var fval = fv_pv + fv_annuity; //you can also just return this immediatly
    return fval;
};
```